# How to output a list of values to a json output with duplicate keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am brand new to python and have hit a roadblock I can't seem to figure out.

I have a list of values. This list could have 1 value or many.

```
['9589503164607', '9589503197375']
```

I need to output this in a json format. My current output looks like this:

```
   "line_items": {"id": ["9589503164607", "9589503197375"]}
```

I need this:

```
{"line_items":[{"id":9589503164607},{"id":9589503197375}]}
```

Currently, I am using a dictionary for this value and the rest that go with this line. However, due to having duplicate keys ("id"), I feel this may be the wrong approach.

```
shop_data = {
    "fulfillment": {
        "location_id": cleanslid,
        "tracking_number": trackingnumber,
        "line_items": {
            "id": iteminvids,
        }
    }
}
```

**iteminvids** is the list I referenced.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be so grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to create a list of dictionaries.

```
"line_items": [{"id": item} for item in list_of_values]
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If your original list is in `lst`, you can do

```py
json.dumps({"line_items": [{"id": i} for i in lst}]})
```